# After calling .OrderBy the resulting List is not Sorted

Tags: c#, list, sorting, unity-game-engine, generics

I have a class called ShipPosition that looks like this:

```
 public int nodesHit = 0;

 PositionNode currentNode;
```

I want to have a list of ships called `shipPositions`in the order of most nodes hit to least. I already have a list of all the ships I want to order in a variable called `allShips` and so, to do this I used .OrderBy() in this line of code:

```
List<ShipPosition> shipPositions = allShips.OrderByDescending(ship => ship.nodesHit).ToList();
```

Yet `shipPositions` stay identical to allShips.

Can you please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Maybe `allShips` is already sorted?

Comment: That was my first thought but it isn't for every case

Comment: Is the `nodesHit` field being modified by anything? Have you checked this field isn't zero for every ship when you're trying to sort them?

Comment: Did you store the sorted list or just call all shops.orderby as you didn’t include the code it’s hard to tell

Answer (score 0):

seemed to work ok for me
here is the fiddle  https://dotnetfiddle.net/5oQO3B

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Ship> ships= new List<Ship>();
        ships.Add(new Ship{NodesHit = 5});
        ships.Add(new Ship{NodesHit = 10});   
        ships.Add(new Ship{NodesHit = 3});
        ships.Add(new Ship{NodesHit = 9});
        ships.Add(new Ship{NodesHit = 1});
        
        foreach (Ship ship in ships.OrderByDescending(ship => ship.NodesHit))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ship.NodesHit.ToString());
        }       
    }
}

public class  Ship{
    public int NodesHit {get; set;}
}
```